# Хранение двоичных данных в БД Firebird

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Добрый день.

Есть некий набор данных, который хочется хранить в таблице БД. Каждый элемент (строка) выглядит примерно так:

```
Name: string[32]
Info: array [0..31]
Data: array [0..255]
```

Вопрос: как оптимальнее и удобнее хранить двоичные данные в таблице - как char[32], char[256] или как blob?

И второй вопрос: можно ли как-то через sql-запрос сохранить/прочитать двоичные данные из поля char (например, используя TQuery), не конвертируя их в строку вида 0xF87D82391BA70...?

Comment: если данные двоичные и в БД есть тип для двоичных данных, то при чем тут вообще строковые типы? двоичные поля всегда читаются через потоки.

Comment: @teran, В том и дело, что у Firebird для бинарных только Blob. Но я смотрю [сюда](https://firebirdsql.org/manual/ru/migration-mssql-data-types-ru.html), а там написано что аналог **binary** в MSSQL - это **char** в Firebird. Вот и думаю, как будет оптимальнее и как вообще это работает.

Comment: для char будет применятся RLE-8 сжатие хранение в "сегменте" данных, для blob будет создан отдельный кластер-"blob сегмент". (т.е. я бы в blob менее 512 байт не ложил бы, а если класте 4096 то хотя бы 2048).

Comment: А зачем конвертировать - прочли string - вывели.

Comment: Может GUID тип вам подойдёт.

Comment: @nick_n_a, потому что там будут две двоичных последовательности - 32 и 256 байт длиной. Как их в текстовый SQL-запрос впихнуть, если там могут быть любые из 256 значений.

Comment: Используйте параметрические запросы. Не мучайте SQL-процессор (компилятор).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для коротких байтовых последовательностей в Firebird рекомендуется использовать тип `CHAR(n) CHARACTER SET OCTETS`.

Для конвертации массива байтов в строку, чтобы передать ее в DataSet, используйте функцию [`SetString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SetString)

Comment: А как их писать/читать через SQL-запросы?

Comment: @Alekcvp, nick_n_a вам уже сказал - используйте параметрический запрос. Это гораздо эффективнее и удобнее.

Comment: Да, наверное так и сделаю, спасибо.